# Do the graphs of $r=\sec 2\theta$ and $r=\csc 2\theta$ consist of two hyperbolas each?

Tags: polar-coordinates

The graphs of the polar equations $r=\sec 2\theta$ and $r=\csc 2\theta$ look like the multiplication and addition signs respectively. They also appear to consist of two hyperbolas each. Is that in fact the case?

If you enter the equations on Desmos, you would get the following:
[image]

The red curve is the graph of $r=\sec 2\theta$ and the blue one is the graph of $r=\csc 2\theta$.

Comment: Have you converted to rectangular coordinates?

Comment: Can that Desmos draw a conic given 5 ponits?

Comment: That doesn't look like a hyperbola, for example, a blue hyperbola looks like it has $y=1$ as an asymptote (in the first quadrant), but also $y=-1$ (in the third quadrant). For a hyperbola, the asymptotes as the same both components.

Comment: @Moisés I mean, you have to take into consideration rotation too, which makes the red and blue curves look *very* similar, which should be very obvious just by looking at it.

Answer (score 5):

Take the curve $r = \sec(2\theta)$.

We have $r \cos(2 \theta)=1$, then $r (\cos^2(\theta) - \sin^2(\theta)) = 1$.

Multiply by $r$ and use $x = r \cos(\theta)$ and $y = r\sin(\theta)$ to get $x^2-y^2=r$.

Squaring and using $r^2 = x^2+y^2$ we get the cartesian equation of the curve:

$$(x^2-y^2)^2 = x^2+y^2$$

This is a quartic, not a quadratic equation, so it's not a hyperbola.

Answer (score 1):

I'll transform $r=\sec{(2\theta)}$ to Cartesian coordinates, and you can do the same for $r=\csc{(2\theta)}$.

$$r=\sec{(2\theta)}$$

$$r=\frac{1}{\cos{(2\theta)}}$$

$$r=\frac{1}{\cos^2(\theta)-\sin^2(\theta)}$$

$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\frac{1}{\cos^2(\arctan(\frac{y}{x}))-\sin^2(\arctan(\frac{y}{x}))}$$

$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2} = \frac{1}{\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)^2 - \left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)^2}$$

$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2-y^2}$$
$$x^2-y^2=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

So.... not *exactly* a hyperbola. This last line will give you one of the "hyperbolas", and if you do $-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ instead, you'll get the other "hyperbola". So... the actuall equation is $x^2-y^2=\pm \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. Or, square both sides and get $x^2+y^2=x^4-2x^2y^2+y^4$. Hope this helps.